# CSS class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gridview

I want to apply a CSS class to a gridview. I tried to apply this style
[reference link](http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/Demo.aspx), so I try this

```
 $(function () {
     $('[ID*=search_data]').on('click', function () {
         var fromdate = $('[ID*=fromdate]').val();
         var todate = $('[ID*=todate]').val();
         var regiondrop = $('[ID*=regiondrop] option:selected')[0].value;
         var tabledata= $('[ID*=tabledata]');
         var obj = {};
         obj.fromdate = fromdate;
         obj.todate = todate;
         obj.regiondrop = regiondrop;
         Getdataa(obj);
         return false;
     });
 });
   function Getdataa(obj) {
             //alert('1');
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "WebForm1.aspx/search_data",
                 data: "{'fromdate':'" + obj.fromdate + "','todate':'" + obj.todate + "','regiondrop':'" + obj.regiondrop + "'}",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 async: true,
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (result) {
                     var final = JSON.parse(result.d).response;
                     console.log(JSON.parse(result.d).response)
                     $("#tabledata").empty();
                     if (final.length > 0) {
                         $("#tabledata").append(
                    "<tr ><th>ID</th><th>OwnerName</th></tr>");

                         for (var i = 0; i < final.length; i++) {
                             if (final[i] !== null) {
                                 $("#tabledata").append("<tr><td>" +
                                final[i][0] + "</td> <td>" +
                                final[i][1] + "</td> <td>" +

                             }
                         }
                     }
                     else {
                         $("#tabledata").hide();
                         $("#Label4").text("No Data");
                     }
                 },
                 error: function (error) {
                     alert("error");

                 }
             });
         }
```

**UPDATE**

ok i update these lines in jquyer after `$("#tabledata").empty();`

```
  $("th").addClass("GridviewScrollHeader");
  $("td").addClass("GridviewScrollItem");
```

but when i build then there is no effect in grid view

And gridview in html

```
 <table id="tabledata">
   </table>
```

When i apply this then gridview is display with simple where as i want to apply this css in gridview when i apply this then gridview display without formatting.. 
what i try 
[image]

what i want
[image: image 2]
So how i apply css ??
any solution?

Comment: So, you don't know what are css selectors, html tags etc?? and **`table` element should only have `tr, td` etc** and WOW two class attributes.

Comment: Please read this: [mcve] - Minimal: most of the code provided doesn't appear to be related to the question (all the ajax loading/click handler).  Complete: You've not included the `<table>` that matches your `<tr><td>`.  Verifiable: Your code does not appear to set `GridviewScrollhHeader` anywhere.

Comment: `<div id="GridView1" class="GridviewScrollHeader"  class="GridviewScrollItem">`???

Comment: do you have some css ? add css class in $("#GridView1").append("<tr class='row-class'><td>"

Comment: @freedomn-m check update

Comment: @Sami check update

Comment: @A.Wolff check update

Comment: It looks like you are building html that ends up as:  `<div><tr><td>` - `tr` can only appear inside a `table`, not inside a `div`.  Try building a "grid" directly in html (not via code) first, then get your code to recreate the working html.

Comment: actually first i try asp gridview but because of static web method and jquery grid-view is not bind nad not display on page.. so then i try to bind grid through html and successfully display in page now i try to apply css in grid-view @freedomn-m

Comment: check update please

Comment: any answer?? please

Answer (score 0):

ok i use this and this work for me

```
$("#tabledata tr:first").addClass('GridviewScrollHeader');
$("#tabledata tr").addClass('GridviewScrollItem');
```